# Facebook requiring account verification for test users

Tags: facebook, roles, facebook-test-users

As the documentation says "Note that a user does not have to be verified to be added as a tester to an app."

All the users I've given a tester role on my sandbox application, the ones that doesn't have a verified account are presented with a message that says "Register as a developer to accept your pending developer requests." If they click that link, then are asked to verify their account.

How is that possible?

Comment: This issue should be fixed now.

Comment: Thank you. This question is about an issue that no longer happens, so what should do about it? Delete it? Leave it? Or is there another action I should take?

Comment: This is happening for me now